# Django loading dictionary values into JSON

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary

I'm trying to take the values from a dictionary, and load them into JSON. I think I almost have it with the bellow code, but it only outputs the first set of values, how do I loop over it so that it will out put all the sets?

```
def storeliqour_view(request, store_id):
    objectdicts = {}
    objects = StoreLiquor.objects.filter(storeID=store_id)
    for i in range(len(objects)):
        objectdicts = model_to_dict(objects[i])
        objectdicts["storename"] = objects[i].storeID.StoreName
    data = [objectdicts.values()] 

    #define response
    response = {
        'aaData': data,
        'iTotalRecords': iTotalRecords,
        'iTotalDisplayRecords': iTotalDisplayRecords,
        'sEcho': request.GET['sEcho']
    }

    #serialize to json
    s = BytesIO()
    json.dump(response, s, cls=MainEncoder)
    s.seek(0)
    return HttpResponse(s.read())
```

Right now it outputs this. As you see, its only one set:
 `{"aaData": [[1, 0.0, 18, 96.6, 7032, false, 2610, "test store"]]}`

How do I get it to output more than one, like this?:
`{"aaData": [[1, 0.0, 18, 96.6, 7032, false, 2610, "test store"], [2, 0.0, 18, 96.6, 7032, true, 2610, "test store"]]}`

Comment: your `data = [objectdicts.values()]` is not part of the for loop so it is only running one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
data = [
    model_to_dict(object).values() + [object.storeID.StoreName]
    for object in objects
]
```

This would work if only the dictionary returned the values in the same order. So it's safer to do the following:

```
data = []
if objects:
    keys = model_to_dict(objects[0]).keys()
    for object in objects:
        d = model_to_dict(object)
        data.append([d[key] for key in keys] + [object.storeID.StoreName])
```

Comment: Yes, the field order was still random

Comment: Field order stayed the same for all the rows regardless of what code I used. But the field order its self was still not in the way its set up in the model.

Comment: Yeah actually you're right, the ability to set the field order is very useful especially for sorting purposes.

Answer (score 1):

```
def storeliqour_view(request, store_id):
    objectdicts = {}
    objects = StoreLiquor.objects.filter(storeID=store_id)
    data = list()
    for i in range(len(objects)):
        objectdicts = model_to_dict(objects[i])
        objectdicts["storename"] = objects[i].storeID.StoreName
        data.append([objectdicts.values()]) 
    # rest of the code here...
```

Comment: The brackets around objectdicts.values() are actually not necessary.

Comment: Yes you are right, I thought you wanted a list of lists. :)